# Chartjs добавить текст внутрь элементов

Tags: javascript, jquery, chart.js

Никак не понять, как можно такое реализовать:

[image: введите сюда описание изображения]

```
new Chart(document.getElementById('myChart'), {
        type: 'doughnut',
        data: {
            datasets: [{
                data: [9.00, 25.00, 25.00, 18.00, 15.00, 8.00],
                backgroundColor: ['#7BE2C9', '#23CEA5', '#FE5F55', '#FF938C', '#FEC8C5', '#B4EEE0'],
                borderWidth: 2,
                borderColor: '#fff',
                hoverOffset: 2
            }],
        },
    });
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Спасла библиотека chartjs-plugin-labels, позволяет данные писать на диаграмме.